# How to disable linear-gradient added by dark mode theme?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, material-design

Why MUI add some random gradient to components ( is one of them) in dark mode?
Is there a way to disable this because that kinda destroy the purpose of my custom theme since it doesnt reflect the exact expected color...

My themeOptions

```
export const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {
palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    primary: {
        main: '#00c9ff',
        light: '#6bfcff',
        dark: '#0079b1'
    },
    secondary: {
        main: '#ffb000',
        light: '#ffe24b',
        dark: '#c68100'
    },
    info: {
        main: '#00c9ff',
        light: '#6bfcff',
        dark: '#0079b1'
    },
    error: {
        main: '#FF4349',
        dark: '#c70032',
        light: '#ff7a75'
    },
    warning: {
        main: '#ff8500',
        dark: '#ea712f',
        light: '#ffb644'
    },
    success: {
        main: '#3da930',
        dark: '#2d7e24',
        light: '#73db60'
    },
    neutral: {
        main: '#64748B',
        contrastText: '#fff'
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @RyanCogswell I see... any way to disable this but keep elevation?

Comment: @RyanCogswell Well you can easily see in the doc when toggling the gradient it has an impact visually https://i.imgur.com/U5tPnJd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is part of how MUI implements the [elevation of the Paper](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.6.2/packages/mui-material/src/Paper/Paper.js#L64) component in dark mode. If you don't want this gradient, you can override it in the theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark"
  },
  components: {
    MuiPaper: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundImage: "unset"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit BasicCard Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: works perfectly thanks!